# Entity Framework Power 4 tools in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, ef-code-first, code-first

I´ve read that one of the best ways to learn Code First with an existing database is to use the EF Power Tools.

I downloaded Entity Framework Power tools beta 4, and installed it in my existing instalation of Visual Studio 2013. After this i restarted Visual Studio.

I created a class library with my entities. From what i understand when the plugin is installed i should get a context menu on the project that will allow me to reverse-engineer a database, i can’t find this menu.

Some possible causes of this of this could be:

- I missed some step of the installation process
- My classes are inside a folder (namespace in .NET) and somehow not recognized by the tool.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Yes, you should see Visual C# -> Data -> ADO.NET Entity Data Model. Not sure what you mean by "I created a class library with my entities" and "My classes are inside a folder" -- the tool generates the POCO classes and context for you.

Comment: Hi, maybe i was unclear. I already have the POCO classes created with the code first anotations but wanted to use the tool as a mean to validate and visualize the model i created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Entity Framework Power tools extension was disabled after the installation. In order to fix this, you need to go to:
Tools-> Extensions and updates, enable the extension and restart Visual Studio 2013.

The other fact that was confusing me was that in order to see the model that is being created by the code-first approach you need to right click the class containing your context (inherits from DbContext) and look inside the "Entity Framework" submenu for "View Entity Data Model".

Hope this helps someone!